# Selecting an external crystal for FPGA

Tags: fpga, crystal

Assuming that the FPGA has a clock multiplier to get much faster frequencies internally, what is good choice for an external crystal?  Let's say I've got a Virtex 7 class FPGA, and I plan to run internally at ~150 MHz and have an external peripheral that needs at 283.0 MHz. The strawman choice for the crystal frequency is currently 40 MHz, but I'm not sure why that was picked.

Is there a minimum frequency?  Maximum frequency of course is dictated by the PCB routing, so I can understand not going too high. But what prevents going lower?

My gut feeling is that anything in the 10 to 50 MHz range is reasonable, but are there trade-offs?

Comment: Check the specs on the DCM's in your FPGA.  There are (typically) upper and lower limits on the frequencies at each step.  So, e.g. your 40MHz crystal would be fine, but < 5MHz or > 250MHz might be a problem.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use a DCM to generate the necessary frequencies inside the FPGA, then it is more dependent on the divider ratio in the DCM than the crystal itself - the DCM is going to generate more phase noise than a decent crystal oscillator.  Also, above a certain point, you need to use LVDS or LVPECL or similar to connect the oscillator to the FPGA with controlled impedance traces, otherwise you can get reflections.  For example, for 10G ethernet, you need a 156.25 MHz crystal, a clock buffer, and controlled impedance differential traces to all of the transciever clock input locations.  A 40 or 50 MHz crystal will cause fewer issues if the phase noise is not a major issue - it generally isn't unless you're multiplying it up to a very high frequency, like 10.3125 GHz for 10G ethernet.  The PLL phase noise is generally dependent on the lowest frequency that you have to divide down to, so you may get better performance if you select a crystal size that allows smaller PLL coefficients - 50 MHz just needs to be multiplied by 3 to get 150, 40 would need to be divided by 4 and then multiplied by 15.  283 MHz is a fun one, though - you may need to do some screwing around in Excel to get that one figured out.  It may be a good idea to pick an oscillator that gives you a small rational fraction for both of the frequencies you need.  Alternatively, it might be a good idea to use two different oscillators.

Generally all of the boards I have worked on have used 50 MHz or 100 MHz oscillators for the core and 156.25 MHz oscillators with clock management circuitry for the transceivers, and then we have just ignored the 50 MHz oscillator and connected everything to one of the transceiver clocks.

Answer (score 2):

If your solution is still in development or the requested frequency is not so common, then I would advise a programmable oscillator like Silicon Laboratories Si570, it's programmable over I²C up to 1.4 GHz in 0.5 Hz steps. Of course this oscillator can't be your main clock source, if the FPGA is used to reprogram the Si570 :)

Comment: That's an absurdly expensive capability unless actually required (the PLL blocks inside the FPGA would normally make it unnecessary).  One might consider placing a footprint for it, but also for a cheaper fixed frequency oscillator.

Comment: There is no common clock divider / multiplier setting in FPGAs MMCM or PLL circuits to produce 283 MHz. Internal clock manipulation circuit also produce many jitter,so an external oscillator is more stable. The Si570 can be bought for 10 .. 50 USD.

Comment: The Xilinx Series 7 FPGAs can use their MMCM to generate 283 MHz from 40, 50 or 100 MHz. This is what the Xilinx Clock Generator wizard just told me. Whether or not it is stable or not is another question, but 283 is well within the fractional range of the hardware.