# Why are 30 MHz crystal oscillators commonly used with FPGAs?

Tags: fpga, oscillator, xilinx, crystal, spartan-3

I am new to FPGAs. I am working on a clone board that has a Spartan 3AN.
There is a 30 MHz crystal oscillator on board.

I have checked another boards and noticed that 30 MHz is commmonly used.

Is there specific reason to use a 30 MHz clock frequency?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/130363/selecting-an-external-crystal-for-fpga

Comment: No specific engineering reason.

Comment: 30 MHz isn't common in my experience. I usually see boards with 25/50/100 MHz oscillators. And there's nothing wrong with reworking a board to replace the oscillator with a more convenient frequency for your application.

Comment: That said, many FPGA's include PLL functionality, to essentially scale whatever crystal used to whatever clock frequency you want.  If PLL jitter is critical in your application, then consider a different crystal.

Comment: 30 MHz? Ha weird choice I would say. All boards I worked on was 50/100.